# How to automate select a text (click and hold mouse) using Javascript and JQuery provide my framework is in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My application has a feature where in the user selects a piece on text by clicking and holding mouse on a a reader page, releasing the mouse later shows a menu to user where he select Highligh option. Text select is highlighted in this way. Can you please help on how to automate this using selenium(java)

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well and and selenium code also which have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

The selenium Actions class allows you to build complex interactions.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java

For example, you might do:

```
driver.clickAndHold().perform();
```

to simulate the user clicking (without releasing) the mouse at the current location.

Comment: I tried the above solution but it didn't work in my case. Is it possible to implement this using Javascript and Jquery